# Python Pandas find value in dataframe regardless of column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to check for a value within a dataframe when it could possibly be in a variety of columns?  Whether using `iterrow` and searching each row for the value and finding which column it is in or just checking the dataframe as a whole and getting its position like `iat` coords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5], 'col3': [8,3,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index('id')
df
```

Sample Data

```
    col2    col3
id      
1   3   8
2   4   3
3   5   9
```

Find 3

```
df.isin([3]).any()
```

Output Column:

```
col2    True
col3    True
dtype: bool
```

Want more detals? Here you go:

```
df[df.isin([3])].stack().index.tolist()
```

Co-ordinates output:

```
[(1, 'col2'), (2, 'col3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the value in dataframe and get the Boolean dataframe for your search. It
gives you all equalities of var1 in df.

```
df[df.eq(var1).any(1)]
```